# Prevent FileDown in WinForms webbrowser control

Tags: c#, .net, browser, webbrowser-control

i need to block file download in webbrowser control in C#.net.. how can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Implementing a Custom Download Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753618(VS.85).aspx)
managed wrapper
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/csEXWB.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Could you be more specific as to what you mean by file download? Opening an html web page is also a file download. You could use the [Navigating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.navigating.aspx) event, inspect the target URL and if you classify it as a file download you could set the `Cancel` property.

Comment: when a prompt for file download appears when you navigate to a certain site. i want to prevent it.